# Is it possible to globally store dimentions of a react element using context and refs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-context

**Background:** I am currently working on a react project in which I have included a sidebar component to display a certain kind of content. The sidebar itself slides in from the right and slides over existing content on the webpage. I'm using portal to render the sidebar into the main content container of the page regardless of where the component is placed in the React DOM. The sidebar has a fixed position and I've so far created some less elegant hooks for measuring the height of the page header, using vanilla javascript, in order for the sidebar not to cover the header. This works quite well. However, the designer has now requested a fixed positioned bottom status bar for showing response messages from API calls. In order for this status bar not to awkwardly cover the sidebar when it is open, I want to use Context to globally store the current height of the status bar element (I assume the status bar is only rendered once at the time in the application). This would, however, required me to be able to update the context store when the size of the referenced React component resizes.

**The actual question**: Is it possible to make a React component reference trigger a side effect (using useEffect) when the component is resized or in any other way use a listener for the reference which is triggered when the component is resized? If not, what other way would you propose?

**Note:** If my questions doesn't make sense or requires more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Just add an event listener for `resize` event, also, please provide a producible example as expected from SO questions: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e show us a slider and ask how to add resize event for it, and show some effort solving it.

Comment: As far as I know, `resize` is only available for the document view, not elements. Checking element height when the view is resized is my current less elegant solution for checking the header height.

Answer (score 1):

There is this hook you could use for this, but depends on which browsers you want to support: https://github.com/rehooks/component-size

You could do something like this:

```
const ref = useRef(null)
const size = useComponentSize(ref)

React.useEffect(() => {
// do something with size
}, [size]);
```